Node.js Sequelize : ReferenceError: model is not defined, when using Through association
I need to create a many to many association in sequelize.
I am having this error :
ReferenceError: alertSMSRule is not defined

Here is the code concerning the error :
file alertSMSrule.model.js :
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const AlertSMSRule = sequelize.define("alertSMSRule", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }
    });
  
    return AlertSMSRule;
  };

file phoneNumber.model.js :
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const PhoneNumber = sequelize.define("phoneNumber", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }
    });
  
    return PhoneNumber;
  };

file index.js :
db.phoneNumber = require("./phoneNumber.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.alertSMSRule = require("./alertSMSRule.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

// line below is giving the error
alertSMSRule.belongsToMany(phoneNumber, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });
phoneNumber.belongsToMany(alertSMSRule, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });

Sequelize is properly imported and initialized.
I have a bunch of other models associations working very well, but they are all hasMany / belongsTo.
This is my first belongsToMany association and it's the only one with error.
Did i miss something about creating a many to many association with sequelize ?
I have checked sequelize doc and forums and everything is telling me this should work this way.
Source : https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/

I found out what is the problem. As we can read on some forums, it's a Javascript error, nothing related to Node.js or Sequelize.
I replaced the code :
alertSMSRule.belongsToMany(phoneNumber, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });
phoneNumber.belongsToMany(alertSMSRule, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });

by :
db.alertSMSRule.belongsToMany(phoneNumber, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });
db.phoneNumber.belongsToMany(alertSMSRule, { through: 'SMSRule_PhoneNumbers' });

